# Copy/Paste Text with Conditional Formatting

Tags: regex, macos, batch-file, sed, text-processing

I have generated a text file with paths of files used in a specific project on my system.
Here is an example of the text file generated

```
%C/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM B/B184_1020RM/B184_1020RM.RDM/B184_C002_1020JV.RDC/B184_C002_1020JV_001.R3D
%C/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM A/A211_102080/A211_102080.RDM/A211_C002_1020W8.RDC/A211_C002_1020W8_001.R3D
```

I am trying to find a way to replace generate another text file from this one that has the commands `fl-cp -sync "/vol/images/` appended to the front of each line and the output path appended to the end of each line with `"/vol/images/SOMEOTHERPATH...`

For example:

```
fl-cp -sync "/vol/images/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM B/B184_1020RM/B184_1020RM.RDM/B184_C002_1020JV.RDC/B184_C002_1020JV_001.R3D" "/vol/images/SOMEOTHERPATH/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM B/B184_1020RM/B184_1020RM.RDM/B184_C002_1020JV.RDC/B184_C002_1020JV_001.R3D" 
fl-cp -sync "/vol/images/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM A/A211_102080/A211_102080.RDM/A211_C002_1020W8.RDC/A211_C002_1020W8_001.R3D" "/vol/images/SOMEOTHERPATH/BL_PROJECTS/PRJ_BMB/INPUT/REEL_06/MISSING_SCAN/240413/Promise Pegasus/BMB/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/DAY 81/20-10-12/CAM A/A211_102080/A211_102080.RDM/A211_C002_1020W8.RDC/A211_C002_1020W8_001.R3D"
```

Is there any way that I can do this easily using terminal or a batch script using ssh?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: I have to do multiple appends npocmaka.
Dont know if this command actually helps or cant figure out how to use it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r -e 's#^%C(.*)#"/vol/images\1"#' -e 's#.*#fl-cp -sync & &#' file.txt
```

Comment: Never used GNU
Would it be possible to do something like this in terminal?

Comment: btw. also other sed's would be fine.

Comment: sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: please replace for OSX `-r`  with `-E` .

Comment: hey Endoro. This works perfectly, except that I might need to change the /vol/images path to a different path when using the fl-cp command. Is there a way to define that in the sed commandline? Can you help describe what the variables and wildcards are doing exactly?